# How to prevent fresh peaches from sinking to the bottom of a buttermilk pound cak?

Tags: baking, cake, fruit

I baked a buttermilk pound cake which was a very thick batter.  The recipe said to dice 3-4 fresh peaches and put them on top of the batter just before it went into the oven.  I did as directed and all the peaches sunk to the bottom and stuck to the bundt pan.  It was delicious but very ungl.  Help!

Answer (score 2):

Dust them in flour or powdered sugar.

This trick is most commonly used with blueberry muffins.